# Knockout checked binding not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am using the Twitter Bootstrap button group along with Knockout.  I feel like I am overlooking something very simple, but, I haven't been able to get the `checked` binding working in this instance.

I have a jsFiddle reproducing the problem here:  http://jsfiddle.net/n5SBa/.

Here is the code from the fiddle:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: ClickScore.bind($data, '0'), css: { active: Score() == '0' }">
            <input type="radio" name="score" value="0" data-bind="checked: Score" /> 0
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: ClickScore.bind($data, '1'), css: { active: Score() == '1' }">
            <input type="radio" name="score" value="1" data-bind="checked: Score" /> 1
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: ClickScore.bind($data, '2'), css: { active: Score() == '2' }">
            <input type="radio" name="score" value="2" data-bind="checked: Score" /> 2
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: ClickScore.bind($data, '3'), css: { active: Score() == '3' }">
            <input type="radio" name="score" value="3" data-bind="checked: Score" /> 3
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: ClickScore.bind($data, '4'), css: { active: Score() == '4' }">
            <input type="radio" name="score" value="4" data-bind="checked: Score" /> 4
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: ClickScore.bind($data, '5'), css: { active: Score() == '5' }">
            <input type="radio" name="score" value="5" data-bind="checked: Score" /> 5
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
```

**Javascript**

```
function SurveyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Score = ko.observable();

    //Events
    self.ClickScore = function (score) {
        self.Score(score);
    };

    //Computations
    self.RecommendationLabel = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.Score() < 8) {
            return "Some question?";
        } else {
            return "Some other question?";
        }
    });

    self.DOMSelectedScore = ko.computed(function() {
        if ($('input[name=score]:checked').val()) {
            return $('input[name=score]:checked').val();
        } else {
            return 'no value!';   
        }
    });
};

var surveyViewModel = new SurveyViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(surveyViewModel);
```

In the example, I'm unable to get the actual radio button selected in the DOM so that it can be properly submitted in my form.

Answer (score 9):

The values of the checkboxes are strings (`"0"`, `"1"`, etc.), but you are setting the value of the observable to a number. The `checked` binding uses strict equality when doing the comparison and doesn't consider the number `1` to equal the string `"1"`.

You can fix this by setting the value of the observable to strings:

```
data-bind="click: ClickScore.bind($data, '1')"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/n5SBa/2/

Comment: I actually do have my code setup to pass in strings, that was a typo on my part.  The issue still exists even in the fiddle you linked (the DOM selected value is still undefined)

Comment: I opened the console and ran `$('input[name=score]:checked')`, and it returns the correct item.

Comment: I'm giving you a +1 because your answer was certainly helpful.  However, I am adding my own answer simply because it looks like the issue was a little more convoluted than I thought.

Answer (score 4):

The `DOMSelectedScore` computed observable doesn't reference any other observable, so it never gets recalculated.

```
self.DOMSelectedScore = ko.computed(function() {
    self.Score(); // subscribe to Score, even if we don't use it.
    var val = $('input[name=score]:checked').val();
    return val || 'no value!';
});
```

Fixing that, it appears that the DOM isn't updated until after the function returns, so the value lags behind one click. To fix this, we need to delay until the DOM has been updated:

```
self.DOMSelectedScore = ko.computed(function() {
    self.Score(); // subscribe to Score, even if we don't use it.
    var val = $('input[name=score]:checked').val();
    return val || 'no value!';
}).extend({throttle:1}); // Wait for the DOM update to complete
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n5SBa/5/

---

To simplify the binding of numbers with knockout, you could define an extension method for observables:

```
ko.observable.fn.asString = function () {
    var source = this;
    if (!source._asString) {
        source._asString = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                return String(source());
            },
            write: function (newValue) {
                source(Number(newValue));
            }
        });
    }
    return source._asString;
};
```

And then

```html
<input type="radio" name="score" value="2" data-bind="checked: Score.asString()"/>
```

Comment: What has me a bit perplexed is how your jsFiddle is working even though it isn't passing in strings (like the other answer says you need to do).

Comment: It seems to have something to do with Twitter Bootstrap. If you remove that js-file, it stops working with plain numbers.

Comment: That's right. Bootstrap sets the checkboxes' `checked` property independently of the bindings.